# Paste column width won't work on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm beginner, and I want to ask something about my code. why paste column width wont work on VBA EXCEL??

Here's my code. thank you.

```
  Sub merge()
Dim P As Integer
On Error Resume Next

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "RAW"

Sheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select


Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("RAW").Range("A1")

Sheets("RAW").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False



For P = 2 To Sheets.Count - 1
    Sheets(P).Activate
    Range("A5").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("RAW").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp)(2)

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

:) In your code you are referencing to a range A1, which is already in "A:Z".

If you want to make the columns B to Z equal to the column A in width, use the following code.

```
Columns("B:Z").columnwidth = columns("A:A").columnwidth
```